# Creating on an imagebutton that openes a new activity onclick crushes

Tags: android-activity, onclick, crash

I tried to do this:
when I click on the imagebutton then it opened new activity (named : TakingPick.class).
It crashed and I don't understand the logcat.
what do I need to do to make it work?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TakingPick.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return false;

}

}
```

xml: activity_main

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"


      android:background="@drawable/bridgebg"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/bridgenew" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:layout_marginBottom="61dp"
    android:src="@drawable/loginfacebook" />
```

The LOGCAT:

```
    06-14 19:36:56.111: E/dalvikvm-heap(14770): Out of memory on a 354168112-byte allocation.
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770): Process: idan.nir.debridge, PID: 14770
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3056)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1613)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.setIcon(ActionBarView.java:1016)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setDefaultIcon(PhoneWindow.java:1543)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at android.app.Activity.initActionBar(Activity.java:2001)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2016)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at idan.nir.debridge.TakingPick.onCreate(TakingPick.java:14)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5431)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
06-14 19:36:56.211: E/AndroidRuntime(14770):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

TakingPick

```
public class TakingPick extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setContentView(R.layout.takingpick);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return false;

}
}
```

xml:takingPick

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bridgebg"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you show code of TakingPick class? something might be happening there ...

Comment: Raunch  looking at code everything looks fine ... try with a regular button also try changing sdk to someother version while building

Comment: try low res. image and see how that goes

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 2):

You got an out of memory exception. One of the bitmaps you are trying to load is to big and causing a memory leak.
If you are using a drawable resource, make sure it's in the correct drawable directory. Also try to reduce the image size and resolution

Comment: No. The photo sized less then 500kb.

Comment: Ok. make sure that you place the resource file in the right directory. I.e drawable-hdpi. If you place an mdpi image in the xxxhdpi dir for example, android would manipulate the image to the right size, what might cause the memory leak you are experiencing right now. Also, Try to avoid from placing images in the default drawable folder. If you are not sure about the size, place it in the "drawable-nodpi" directory. this way android won't manipulate the image and would just use it as it is.